# Recursively read files and folders and create hyperlinks to them using PHP

Tags: php

I have following file stucture in my directory.

```
file.txt
file2.txt
  folder1
    file1.txt
  folder2
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
```

For read files and folders I use this script

```
function read_dir($dir, $mark = '-') {
    $d = opendir($dir);
    while ($name = readdir($d)) {       
        if ($name == '.' || $name == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        elseif (is_dir($name)) {
            echo $mark.'<div class="folder"><b>'.$name.'</b></div>';
            read_dir($name);                
        }
        else
            echo $name.'<br />';
    }
}

read_dir('/path/to/myfolder/.');
```

I get html

```
file.txt<br />
file2.txt<br />-
    <div class="folder"><b>folder1</b></div>
    file1.txt<br />-
    <div class="folder"><b>folder2</b></div>
    file1.txt<br />
file2.txt<br />
```

I need set links to download files, like

```
<a href="path/to/myfolder/file.txt">file.txt</a><br />
<a href="path/to/myfolder/file2.txt">file2.txt</a><br />-
<div class="folder"><b>folder1</b></div>
<a href="path/to/myfolder/folder1/file1.txt">file1.txt</a><br />-
<div class="folder"><b>folder2</b></div>
<a href="path/to/myfolder/folder1/file1.txt">file1.txt</a><br />
<a href="path/to/myfolder/folder1/file2.txt">file2.txt</a><br />
```

How need to change script for set links to files to download?

Comment: What links are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you mean by "How I can set links to files list?".

Comment: Link to download file <a href='/'>filename</a>

Comment: Unclear question. What do you get exactly? And what do you want instead? There is no  `<a...>` anywhere in your code, so you can't expect to get one ;-)